# Do something when an action has been dispatched

Tags: angular, ngxs

Let's say we an action `SyncUserData`, which returns observable that listen to changes from the database. Whenever there's a change, the action dispatches the action `new PatchUserData(newData)`.

The `SyncUserData` action is dispatched (only once) from `ngxsOnInit` of the state.

In a different section (e.g., component), I want to do something whenever the action `PatchUserData` is dispatching. Something like this:

```
this.store.onDispatch(PatchUserData).subscribe();
```

I was looking a bit in the source, and I didn't find something similar to my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to subscribing to the state directly is to use the NGXS action stream to be notified when a specific action has been dispatched/completed see the documentation for [action handlers](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/advanced/action-handlers).

From the official doco:

```
@Component({ ... })
export class CartComponent {
  constructor(private actions$: Actions) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.actions$.pipe(ofActionSuccessful(CartDelete)).subscribe(() => alert('Item deleted'));
  }
}
```

Comment: You're right. I used this approach after I posted this question. It seemed more convenient.

Comment: Yes I've used this quite a bit now too - especially if I want to do something but don't really care about looking at the current state

Comment: @EliyaCohen it is seems like an answer to the question

Comment: how we can use it for check completion of one action out of few?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to subscribe to a certain event in your case, you can subscribe to `userData` in your store and have the lastest version of it no matter whatever action changed it. Modify next sample according to your data models and subscribe to observable:

```
import { Select } from '@ngxs/store';

@Select(({ userData }: AppState) => userData)
  userData$!: Observable<UserData>;
```

More on select: https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/concepts/select

Comment: Does `@Select({ userData }: AppState) => userData)` equals to `@Select(state => state.app.userData)`?

Comment: No, its equal to `@Select(state => state.userData)`

Comment: Ok thx, but if so, then why wouldn't you type `@Select(state => state.userData)` instead?

Comment: Use whatever suits you more, I just like that style